# Image not getting saved (download) in iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm using

```
     UIImage *viewImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:self.imageURL]]];
NSLog(@"UIImage : %@",viewImage);
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
} else {
    NSLog(@"URL IS  %@", assetURL);
    [self assignDictonary:viewImage withURL:assetURL withMediaType:@"public.image"];

}
}];
[library release];
```

OR

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,(unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]]], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
});
```

To save the image..

It's working fine with all the versions above iOS 5...

It's not working with iOS 4.3...

Why is it so.. And can any one suggest me some other solution..

Comment: What's the image URL used? Is it local or remote? If its remote, its probable that you're trying to create the image and save it, but it hasn't downloaded before you try to write it to the saved photos album.

Comment: its a URL from server.. but its working fine with iOS 5 and above..

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the image is loading after you try to invoke saving the image into the assets library.

An alternative approach would be to use NSURLConnection to download the image, rather than trust the

+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] method. This is how I'd do it on iOS5+:

```
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL  URLWithString: @"https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/7335737088/h25EA2F17/"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: imageURL];
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                     queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
   {
     UIImage *viewImage = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
     ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

     [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum: [viewImage CGImage]
                               orientation: (ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation]
                           completionBlock:
      ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
      {
        if (error)
        {
          NSLog(@"error");
        }
        else
        {
          NSLog(@"URL IS  %@", assetURL);
        }
      }];
     NSLog(@"UIImage : %@",viewImage);
   }];
```

Comment: its throwing an exception here "[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)"

Comment: What's the exception say? Do you have a backtrace?

Comment: i think this function "[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                     queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
   {" is not supported by iOS 4.3..

Comment: Good point, the block based syntax isn't supported on iOS 4 - there's still the delegate way of doing things, however. Its messier.

Comment: dataWithContentsOfURL is synchronic, there is no way the saving is before the image loading

Comment: Been looking some more into the issue: Or Arbel is completely correct, dataWithContentsOfURL is synchronous ... so its not the first hypothesis I thought it was. Have you experimented with -[ALAssetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:]? (Be warned: its iOS 4.1 and above only).

Comment: ya i know but i want to know whats the problem with iOS 4.3.. why its not working with iOS 4.3.. and its working fine with iOS 5 and above..

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're releasing the library instance before the saving completes. try moving the release in to the completion block:

```
UIImage *viewImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:self.imageURL]]];
NSLog(@"UIImage : %@",viewImage);
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
} else {
    NSLog(@"URL IS  %@", assetURL);
    [self assignDictonary:viewImage withURL:assetURL withMediaType:@"public.image"];

}
[library release];
}];
```

Comment: replace NSLog(@"error"); with NSLog(@"%@",[error description]); and let's see what is says

Comment: error : Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3310 "Data unavailable" UserInfo=0x6d71910 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Launch the Photos application, NSLocalizedDescription=Data unavailable}

Comment: what happens when you launch the photo application?

Comment: nothing will happen it will just show the message.. "its not getting hanged or throwing exception.."

Comment: can you see the photos in the native photo app? can you take a picture?

Comment: i have shown that pic on my UIImage view with that URL but when i'm trying to download its giving error..